# Render SVG as Image with Semantic UI React

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react and I have some problems rendering a simple image.
After importing image:

```
import { Button, Image, Header, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
```

This is not working

```
   <Image floated='right' size='mini' src={require('./icons/logo.svg')}/>
```

[image]

And neither this:

```
import logo from './icons/logo.svg'
 ...
<Image floated='right' size='mini' src={logo}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7219783/riccardo-persiani), that error is telling you that in your Webpack config you do not have a loader configured to handle SVG files. This is probably the one you want to use: [svg-loader](https://github.com/dolbyzerr/svg-loader)